# non-conformable arrays in matrix multiply R

Tags: r, matrix

```
> dim(ginv(cov_mat_month))
[1] 495 495
> class(mu_hat_month)
[1] "matrix"
> class(cov_mat_month)
[1] "matrix"
> dim(mu_hat_month)
[1] 495   1
> c = ginv(cov_mat_month) * mu_hat_month

Error in ginv(cov_mat_month) * mu_hat_month : non-conformable arrays
```

Matrix(495*495) * Matrix(495*1), why there always has error "non-conformable arrays"? Totally confused.

Comment: Operator `*` on matrices does multiply elementwise. The matrices do not have the same dimension. What do you want: matrix /vector multiplication? If yes use `A %*% b` where `A` is `ginv(...)` and b is `mu_hat_month`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I mess up R with Octive/Matlab. In Octive, it works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this

```
c = ginv(cov_mat_month) %*% mu_hat_month
```

instead of this

```
c = ginv(cov_mat_month) * mu_hat_month
```

hope this solves your problem.